# using a formula to make a statement with the use of greater than, less than symbol

Tags: notation

I am trying to make statement using the greater than less, less than symbol. I am unsure if the use of $\lt\gt$ symbols have to facing the same direction in an equation. 
Could you say:
$x \lt x + y \gt y$
would this mean that $x$ is less than $x+y$ and also $y \lt x+y$

I'm going to use this for the engraving in my (future) husband wedding band. Just trying to say that we are better together. Hope this makes sense!

Thank you!!!

Comment: The engraving would be:      a < a + m > m   with a= Adam; m= Melissa

Comment: It does not seem to be mathematically the best representation but as engraving - why not?

Comment: Well my future husband is an aerospace engineer. So just want it to make sense at least ;)

Comment: It makes sense to me, but I'm not a math major!

Comment: It's hard to interpret it any other way, but mathematically I wouldn't call it good notation.

Comment: yes, it's been a long time sense math class. I thought the symbols were suppose to always face the same way when you wrote out an equation. So it's bad notation in that sense?

Comment: It would make more sense to me to add parentheses but that's just me, $a < (a+m) > m$

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in that the interpretation of $x<x+y>y$ would be $x<x+y$ and $y<x+y$. This isn't the usual way such a thing is notated - sometimes people write both equations, and sometimes people write $x,y<x+y$. Still, personally I think $x<x+y>y$ has a satisfying symmetry which $x,y<x+y$ doesn't have.

And of course, congratulations!

Comment: Thank you!!! That clarifies it perfectly :) REALLY appreciate you taking the time to answer my question!!